# python findall() method does not recognize regular expression with (){}

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, findall

I am learning the `findall()` method in the regular expression section. I have a problem which I did not find the solution and explanation. The `findall()` method does not recognize the regular expression pattern correctly or as I expected when I used `{}` to specify the number of the string for matching.

To be explicity, I take the example from the book. Here is the code:

```
import re
haRegex = re.compile(r'(Ha){3}')
mo = haRegex.findall('HaHaHaHaHaHa')
```

when I run the script, I got this:

```
['Ha', 'Ha']
```

However, when I replaced `(Ha){3}` with `HaHaHa`, I got

```
['HaHaHa', 'HaHaHa']
```

which is I expected from the first script.

Besides, the pattern worked perfectly with `search()` method. I got

```
'HaHaHa'
```

with `group()` method.

Anyone knows what happened?

Comment: Use a non-capturing group, `r'(?:Ha){3}'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it works!!! Thanks a lot. With your solution, I found out that the parenthesizes in the pattern were recognized as grouping. I understand now. Thanks again.